# A function like toDataURL()

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for an HTML method that will let me print out my HTML code in a text box:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="showHere">
SOME TEXT
</textarea>
<button onclick="show()">

show = function(){

var t = (FUNCTION I AM LOOKING FOR);

document.getElementById("showHere").innerHTML = t;

}
```

The function I have in mind is like the `HTML5 CANVAS` tag: 
toDataURL()

I have heard from a friend(He couldn't think of the name) that there is an HTML method to HELP me achieve this.

Thanks a lot for your help! I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: I am not sure whether I got this... Do you want a function which allows you to insert the HTML (source) code of the whole document into a textarea?

Comment: Yes, sir! You got it!

Comment: Shouldn't `innertext` work in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be as simple as this:

```
document.getElementById("showHere").value = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

**Edit:** Modifying CSS through a textarea

```
<!-- everything before the head -->
<head>
  <!-- other stuff in the head -->
  <style id="user-css"></style>
  <script>
    var textarea, style;
    // Wait for document to load
    window.onload = function() {
      // Find textarea and style element
      textarea = document.getElementById('css-code');
      style = document.getElementById('user-css');
      textarea.value = style.innerHTML;
      // Update CSS on change
      textarea.onkeyup = textarea.onchange = function() {
        style.innerHTML = textarea.value;
      };
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea id="css-code"></textarea>
</body>
```

To make persistent changes, you will need either server or complex client logic, e.g. using cookies, server-based storage (perhaps sessions) or something like local storage.

Comment: What if i have a site, that lets people costomize the CSS, but whenever they refresh the site, it will revert back to the default colors.

Comment: What if i want to save their work by using this function? how could i do that? I have tried it(just now) but it gives me the websites default settings

Comment: @bob If this is about CSS only, you should not use the code of the whole page but rather bind the value of the textarea to the contents of a `<style>` tag.

Comment: Ok, how would i do this? Using `id` tags and JS or what?

Comment: Great work! I can now see how to do it! thanks a ton!

Comment: could I do it so that when any of those areas get changed it will show up in the `textarea`??